# SQL Query to select top 1 message from every sender

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a private messaging system, this is what i want to do..

[image]

If ToId or fromid is 42  then query must return just one(most recent row) row for every toid/fromid associated with toid/from 42.

In this case it should be rows with msg ids..
3,4,6,7

Comment: `most recent` in which context?

Comment: I guess messageid as date is unused (at present)?

Comment: i will use date.. just assume date column is filled.

Comment: I've not checked this on sqlserver but... `select msgid, fromid, toid, msg, date from messagetable mt1 where msgid in (select fromid, toid, max(msgid) as msgid from messagetable mt2 group by fromid, toid)`?

Comment: @Arbaaz . . . Are you sure that you want "6"?  It has the same pair as "7".

Comment: @GordonLinoff i just realized that ! i would want just one of the two to be retrieved either 6 or seven which ever is more recent

Comment: Ah, ok... if by date... `select msgid, fromid, toid, msg, date from messagetable mt1 left outer join (select fromid, toid, max(date) from messagetable mt2 group by fromid, toid) as msgmax on mt1.fromid = msgmax.fromid and mt1.toid = msgmax.toid and mt1.date = msgmax.date;`... Ah.. but not with 6 and 7. Back to drawing board (though I did wonder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an application of `row_number()`.

```
select msgid, fromid, toid, msg, date
from (select t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by fromid, toid
                                order by msgid desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
      where 42 in (fromid, toid)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This uses `msgid` to determine the most recent value.  Just change the order by to `order by date desc` to use date.

If you want the  most recent for unique pairs (regardless of order), then a bit more logic is required:

However, you need to put the messages in a "canonical" format, so (42, 43) is the same as (43, 42).  The key is partitioning by the smaller value and the larger, in that order:

```
select msgid, fromid, toid, msg, date
from (select t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by (case when fromid < toid then fromid else toid end),
                                             (case when fromid < toid then toid else fromid end)
                                order by msgid desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
      where 42 in (fromid, toid)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: First one is working fine but I am getting this error while running the send query... 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I relaized that i would want msgid 3,4,6 or 3,4,7 only

Comment: @Arbaaz . . . The infamous missing `end` on a `case` statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff your query does work but what exactly does partition and case are for? i am a total noob :P

Answer (score 0):

This will select top 1 message id(MsgId) from your table:

```
   select MAX(MsgId) messageID
   from table 
   group by FromId, ToId
   order by messageID
```